# Does Baines Avenue give any advantages over the highway?

Tags: anno-2070

Does Baines Avenue give any advantages over the highway? It doesn't seem to have any differences except for the fact that it costs 10 credits more.

Answer (score 2):

Banes Avenue and Green Boulevard don't offer any speed advantages over the Highway, they just have a different visual appearance.

The only other thing to note is that Tilda Jorgensen does not like it when you pave a lot of your island with anything besides Roads or Green Boulevard.